# Why do we use the length of the canard as 1/3 of the wing?

Tags: canard

Twisted canard is our project, so we are designing and analysing the model. We compare the twisted canard with an untwisted canard to find the best among them.

The problem is we designed a canard of 1/3 length of the main wing(delta wing) as many fighter aircrafts used. So now the question is why the length should be 1/3 of the main wing?

Comment: Are you asking why a canard wing is usually one third the length of the main wing? Can you give an example of an aircraft you're using as a source?

Comment: The ratio depends on the design performance of the aircraft. Is your design supersonic (say M1.5–2)? If not, you probably shouldn't be basing it off fighter jets (the delta wings also only makes sense on supersonic designs).

Answer (score 0):

I think its due to increasing the lift of the wing most optimal.

The canard will form a vortex that sweeps over the main wing and will increase lift. On the NASA technical report server there is several documents that cover canards:

[NASA document](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a063819.pdf)

The 1/3 is probably designed so that the vortex passes over the wing in the place that will result in the most lift, while not having the canards be too large due to drag.